# How do I get the tap coordinates on a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uibutton, storyboard

I'm using XCode 4.4 developing for iOS 5 on an iPad and am using the Storyboard layout when creating my custom button.

I have the touch event correctly working and logging but now I want to get the x/y coordinates of the tap on my custom button.

If possible, I'd like the coordinates to be relative to the custom button instead of relative to the entire iPad screen.

Here's my code in the .h file:

```
- (IBAction)getButtonClick:(id)sender;
```

and my code in the .m file:

```
    - (IBAction)getButtonClick:(id)sender {

        NSLog(@"Image Clicked.");
    }
```

Like I said, that correctly logs when I tap the image.

How can I get the coordinates of the tap?

I've tried a few different examples from the internet but they always freeze when it displays a bunch of numbers (maybe the coordinates) in the log box. I'm VERY new to iOS developing so please make it as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Artern is asking the right question. Do you really need to know the coordinates within a button, or do you just want to know which button was clicked (in which case, you don't need Vladimir's excellent suggestion of "Sender and Event"), but rather you can just look at the `sender` to determine which button was clicked.

Comment: I need the coordinates because I'm displaying an image as a UIButton and  I need to know where on that image the user tapped. I already know how to tell which button was clicked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get touch location you can use another variant of button action method: `myAction:forEvent:` (if you create it from IB interface note "sender and event" option in arguments field: [image])

Then in your action handler you can get touch location from event parameter, for example:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:sender];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, I'm still getting the same error I get when I tried other code from online. "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde26e40
2012-08-07 10:29:36.126 Differences[41044:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DifferencesViewController getButtonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde26e40'" Got any ideas?

Comment: @user1262552, you still have getButtonClick: method attached to your button action, check your storyboard file or code to make sure button action is tied to existing method of your view controller

Comment: And the app seems to freeze when I tap on the image.

Comment: Thank you, Valdimir. That was the problem. I now have the coordinates showing exactly how I want them. Thanks again!

Comment: Still helping developers in 2015!

Comment: @Developer add target with selector you specified: `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside]`

Answer (score 3):

Incase of Swift 3.0 the accepted answer works same except syntax will be changed as follows:

**Swift 3.0:**

```
 @IBAction func buyTap(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
     let myButton = sender as! UIButton
     let touches = event.touches(for: myButton)
     let touch = touches?.first
     let touchPoint = touch?.location(in: myButton)
     print("touchPoint\(touchPoint)")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your overall coordinates (with reference to the screen), you need to create a `CGPoint` that contains the coordinates of your touch. But to do that, you need to get that touch first. So start by getting the touch event, then by making that point using the `locationInView`method. Now, depending on when you want to log the touch - when the user touches down, or when they lift their finger -, you have to implement this code in the `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded` method. Let's say you do `touchesEnded`, which passes an NSSet cales "touches" containing all the touch events.

```
UITouch *tap = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [tap locationInView:self.view];
```

"touchPoint" will now contain the point at which the user lifts their finger. To print out the coordinates, you just access the x and y properties of that point:

```
CGFloat pointX = touchPoint.x;
CGFloat pointY = touchPoint.y;
NSLog(@" Coordinates are: %f, %f ", pointX, pointY);
```

That should output the coordinates of the touch. Now to have it be referenced to whatever button you're using, I would suggest you just manually subtract the values for the button's coordinates from the point. It seems like a simple solution, and honestly I don't know a way of getting coordinates with reference to another object, unless you make a view based on that object, and pass it to `locationInView` instead of `self.view`.

For more info on touches, there's a great set of tutorials [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_Touch%2C_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application).