# restrict my touch area to part of UIImageVIew

Tags: ios5, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController into which i added a UIImageView with CGRectMake(0,0,1024,704). (768-nav bar ht-status bar ht=704). I am working in landscape mode only. I added tap gesture to this UIImageView. But i want to restrict this tap area to the height to 604. This picture should make it a bit clear.
The area with red lines is the UIImageView and the are that has green and red lines is the area that does not need touch event.
[image]

Any idea how to go about doing this?

Comment: did you read this? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11848120/1372349]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11848120/1372349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`locationInView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/locationInView%3a) method in `UITabGestureRecognizer` to know where the user tapped, and respond accordingly.